# Bigtable data trigger/watch

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

I am looking to get data from bigtable into dataflow in an unbounded fashion such that the processing is triggered based on continuos inserts into the table. The document (https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/dataflow-hbase) only talks about bounded read using scans. Does the connector or big table support this model at all?

Answer (score 2):

The current `BigtableIO` connector does not support this model of continuous update monitoring, but it would certainly be useful. It is tracked as feature request [BEAM-45](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-45).